# $n_1={m_1}^2+{m_2}^2+{m_3}^2+{m_4}^2$, $n_2={k_1}^2+{k_2}^2+{k_3}^2+{k_4}^2$, so we have $n_1n_2={l_1}^2+{l_2}^2+{l_3}^2+{l_4}^2$. How to find $l_i$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, education

$n_1={m_1}^2+{m_2}^2+{m_3}^2+{m_4}^2$, $n_2={k_1}^2+{k_2}^2+{k_3}^2+{k_4}^2$, so we have $n_1n_2={l_1}^2+{l_2}^2+{l_3}^2+{l_4}^2$.
How to find $l_i$?
I remember I read something about this, but don't remember what is this. Can anyone can tell or show me some material about this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's another of Euler's formulas: [Euler's four square identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_four-square_identity)

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer to me

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I thought of it as well. The thing is that if I or anyone else commented about Euler's four square identity then the question is answered in a way, int sense that is pointless for anyone else to answer it(unless they offer a brand new proof). So we are left with a question that is practically answered but it shows in the unanswered log. So what is the best course of action in this case?(Genuinely asking, I am not implying that me answering was the best course.)

Comment: Alright, that is a good way to look into it(never thought like this).I guess then your answer is justified.I merely mentioned as i have seen this practice not very encouraged.Anyway good find!

Comment: It's not necessarily a good find. One could say that the best practice would have been to comment the link and then ask op to delete the question so that it doesn't appear as unanswered. In general I think there are some problems with the site in stuff like this.